# ARM/Cortex-M comparison data source: Can someone give me a little lay of the land?

Tags: arm, i2s

So there are soo many manufacturers making ARM and ARM Cortex-Mx chips and a few of them have I²S and I even saw one with S/PDIF.  [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M) gives me *some* lay of the land, but I need some hand-holding (or spoon-feeding).

The only hard data I have been looking at is that at ST Microelectronics.

Is there a good central spreadsheet that, even if it's a couple years old, lays out the different ARM and ARM Cortex-M chips from various manufacturers with qualitative details (like has or has not FPU, DSP, 64-bit, I²S or whatever interface) and quantitative details (like on-chip RAM size, cache size, instruction clock rate)?

As you might imagine, I am wondering what chip might be best for audio processing with multiple channels (like 4 or even 8 or even 16 in and maybe 4 out) and with a decent high-speed method of getting the multi-channel samples in and out (if not I²S, something better).

It's not really a mixer, but think of it as if it is. More innies than outies.

I just wanna know where to begin finding and looking up chip data.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56099/discussion-on-question-by-robert-bristow-johnson-arm-cortex-m-comparison-data-so).

Comment: booo!  OP is appropriate and the comments are appropriate.

Comment: 3 votes to reopen.